owasp/modsecurity-crs:nginx libmodsecurity3 version 3.0.12 open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
I have been trying to set up owasp/modsecurity-crs:nginx to provide WAF security to my application
The reverse proxy is defined by
# Use the OWASP ModSecurity CRS image with Nginx
FROM owasp/modsecurity-crs:nginx

# Copy the custom Nginx configuration file templates
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.template
COPY letsencrypt /etc/letsencrypt
COPY modsecurity.d/modsecurity.conf /etc/nginx/templates/modsecurity.d/modsecurity.conf.template

COPY modsecurity.d/unicode.mapping /etc/nginx/unicode.mapping

# Set up the entrypoint
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

in my modsecurity.conf I have set
SecUnicodeMapFile /etc/nginx/unicode.mapping 20127

and the containers all spin up except upon running the modsecurity entrypoint scripts all succeed and then
nginx_1   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/modsecurity.d/modsecurity.conf.template to /etc/nginx/modsecurity.d/modsecurity.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/modsecurity.d/modsecurity-override.conf.template to /etc/nginx/modsecurity.d/modsecurity-override.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/modsecurity.d/setup.conf.template to /etc/nginx/modsecurity.d/setup.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.template to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/conf.d/logging.conf.template to /etc/nginx/conf.d/logging.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/conf.d/default.conf.template to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/conf.d/modsecurity.conf.template to /etc/nginx/conf.d/modsecurity.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/includes/proxy_backend.conf.template to /etc/nginx/includes/proxy_backend.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/includes/location_common.conf.template to /etc/nginx/includes/location_common.conf
nginx_1   | 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/includes/proxy_backend_ssl.conf.template to /etc/nginx/includes/proxy_backend_ssl.conf
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/90-copy-modsecurity-config.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/91-update-resolver.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/92-update-real_ip.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/93-update-proxy-ssl-config.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/94-activate-plugins.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/95-activate-rules.sh
nginx_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1   | 2024/06/20 21:51:36 [notice] 1#1: ModSecurity-nginx v1.0.3 (rules loaded inline/local/remote: 0/7/0)
**nginx_1   | 2024/06/20 21:51:36 [notice] 1#1: libmodsecurity3 version 3.0.12
nginx_1   | 2024/06/20 21:51:36 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx_1   | nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)**
backwards_is_the_new_forwards_nginx_1 exited with code 1

I'm really stumped, I have tried messing around with permissions inside the container but that seems to defeat the point of using the WAF and I haven't seen any related issues
from this question, I tried
RUN touch /run/nginx.pid \
 && chown -R api-gatway:api-gatway /run/nginx.pid /cache/nginx

and from this question I have tried messing around with the user defined in the nginx.conf

Are you using official CRS docker image?
